# The identification variable 'TO_DATE' is not defined in the FROM clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to add TO_DATE () to be able to pass the date in string format and generate a query that filters by date, but when sending TO_DATE it generates this error

the query is :

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "MvTarifa.obtenerTarifaPorCc", query = "SELECT m FROM MvTarifa m "
        + "INNER JOIN m.maTarifero t "
        + "INNER JOIN m.listaMvCtacteTariferos ct "
        + "WHERE m.tarffechainivigen <= TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND m.tarffechafinvigen > TO_DATE('"+"TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND t.tarffechainivigen <= TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND t.tarffechafinvigen > TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND ct.cttafechainivigen <= TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND ct.cttafechafinvigen >= TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND ct.ctactenumero = :numeroCuentaCorriente "
        + "AND m.ccorcodigo = :tarifaAsociadaCtaCte "
        + "AND t.tarimeson = :tarifaAsociadaMeson "
        + "AND t.emprcodigo = :codigoEmpresa "
        + "AND ct.emprcodigo = :codigoEmpresa "
        + "AND m.tarfversion > 0"),
```

Comment: I don't know Java, but surely there must be a way to pass appropriately typed variables as binds, rather than passing strings and asking the database to convert them?

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove the single quotes around all the bind variables:

```sql
TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Instead of:

```sql
TO_DATE(':fechaactual', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or, as you put it with extra string concatenation operations:

```sql
TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Removing the single quotes should be repeated for all the other instances of `TO_DATE` as you want to use the bind variable rather than a string literal.

Also, you do not want `TO_DATE` nested inside a string literal:

```java
"AND m.tarffechafinvigen > TO_DATE('"+"TO_DATE('"+":fechaactual"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"+"', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
```

Should be:

```java
"AND m.tarffechafinvigen > TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
```

And you need an `ON` expression following each `INNER JOIN` to specify the join condition.

```java
@NamedQuery(
  name = "MvTarifa.obtenerTarifaPorCc",
  query = "SELECT m FROM MvTarifa m "
        + "INNER JOIN m.maTarifero t "
        + "ON ( <INSERT YOUR JOIN CONDITION HERE> )"
        + "INNER JOIN m.listaMvCtacteTariferos ct "
        + "ON ( <INSERT YOUR JOIN CONDITION HERE> )"
        + "WHERE m.tarffechainivigen <= TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND   m.tarffechafinvigen >  TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND   t.tarffechainivigen <= TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND   t.tarffechafinvigen >  TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND  ct.cttafechainivigen <= TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND  ct.cttafechafinvigen >= TO_DATE(:fechaactual, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "AND  ct.ctactenumero = :numeroCuentaCorriente "
        + "AND   m.ccorcodigo = :tarifaAsociadaCtaCte "
        + "AND   t.tarimeson  = :tarifaAsociadaMeson "
        + "AND   t.emprcodigo = :codigoEmpresa "
        + "AND  ct.emprcodigo = :codigoEmpresa "
        + "AND   m.tarfversion > 0"),
```

Then you will probably get a valid query that returns zero rows as you are filtering on when the dates are simultaneously `>=` and `<` the same value; that is never going to be true.

Comment: [79, 86] The identification variable 'TO_DATE' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[141, 148] The identification variable 'TO_DATE' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[203, 210] The identification variable 'TO_DATE' is not defined in the FROM clause.
[265, 272] The identification variable 'TO_DATE' is not defined in the FROM clause.

Comment: @VíctorEduardoDuqueRosales Have you tried to get your query to run directly against the database? Connect using SQL/Plus (or an equivalent) and get the query to be syntactically valid (with hard-coded values rather than bind variables) and to generate the rows that you want and then copy-paste that into your Java code and change it back to using bind variables.

Comment: if I have tried the query, in Dbeaver, the problem is with javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
this library does not let me use TO_DATE

Comment: public List<MvTarifa> obtenerTarifasPorEmpresaDom(long codigoEmpresa, boolean esDomicilio) {
        try {
            System.out.println("QUERY!!!! " + date);
            Query consulta = em.createNamedQuery("MvTarifa.obtenerTarifaPorEmpresaDom", MvTarifa.class);
            //consulta.setParameter("fechaactual", new Date());
            consulta.setParameter("fechaactual", date);
            consulta.setParameter("codigoEmpresa", codigoEmpresa);
            consulta.setParameter("tarifaAsociadaCtaCte", TARIFA_ASOCIADA_A_CTA_CTE_NO);